# Why is it possible to @Inject a @Stateless EJB into a @SessionScoped Managed Bean?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, ejb, ejb-3.0, cdi

Why is it possible to `@Inject` a `@Stateless` EJB into a `@SessionScoped` Managed Bean?

I am just very curious because it is not possible to use a `@RequestScoped` Managed Bean in a `SessionScoped` Managed Bean as managed property.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why is it possible to @Inject a @Stateless EJB into a @SessionScoped
>   Managed Bean?

That makes perfect sense. You might want to access a stateless component (eg a validation service) from within a stateful service (eg a shopping process). CDI references are [proxied](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/injection.html#d0e1429), so there is no technical problem with the resolution.

> I am just very curious because it is not possible to use a
>   @RequestScoped Managed Bean in a SessionScoped Managed Bean as managed
>   property.

You are referring to the JSF scopes, not the CDI scopes, right? I cannot tell why that constellation might be forbidden, but both specifications are completely unrelated, so there is no "*if A is true in JSF then B must be true in CDI*"-relationship...

Comment: Jan, @RequestScoped is also a CDI scope. See http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/api/1.0-SP1/javax/enterprise/context/RequestScoped.html Note there are elements of this scope which have nothing to do with web requests, Servlets, JSP or JSF etc. Although from the way the question is asked I think OP is indeed talking about the JSF scopes with the same name ;)

Comment: Yep, `@RequestScoped` is certainly a CDI scope as well. The JSF reference was triggered by "managed property"

Comment: Yes, I am talking about the `@RequestScoped` from JSF. It is not allowed in JSF because of the lifetime of the beans. I thought it might be the same for EJBs. Is the lifecycle different in EJBs compared to Managed Beans(JSF)?

Comment: yes. but you are encouraged to ask new questions in separate threads :)